# Porque é impressa parte de uma linha de forma repetida ao se ler um arquivo csv?

Tags: c++

Olá. Escrevi um código para ler um arquivo de dados csv e imprimir seus dados na tela, porém o último sobrenome e idade se repetem na última linha.

O que existe de errado nó código para imprimir esta última linha?

Posteriormente quero armazenar os dados lidos em um struct.

**Código:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream file;
    file.open("dados.csv");

    if (file.is_open()) {

    string nome;
    string sobrenome;
    string idade;

    while(file.good()) {

        getline(file,nome,',');
        getline(file,sobrenome,',');
        getline(file,idade,'\n');

        cout << nome << " " << sobrenome << " " << idade << endl;
        cout << "--------------------" << endl;

    }
    file.close();
    }

    else {

    cout << "O arquivo não pode ser aberto!" << endl;
}


}
```

**Arquivo dados.csv:**

```
Pedro,Dias,31
Maria,Silva,20
Joao,Ferreira,35
```

**Saída após execução:**

[image: saída do programa]

Comment: Provavelmente, o seu arquivo "dados.csv" tem uma linha "a mais" (depois do 35, deve ter um `'\n'`), o que faz com que o looping execute além das 3 linhas. Tente editar o arquivo csv, apagar a última linha em branco (o cursor deve ficar na frente do 35), salvar e testar novamente